# Saving and reading objects from plist cause huge memory of 2G

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a system to save lots of images to plist , that works good, except 2 main problems.

first, when it start the process ,memory on xcode goes to 2G ! (and down when done)
Second, it takes too long(10+ seconds for 100 images)compared to `NSUserdefaults`, which i told is slower than this .

I am archiving the data first.

What am i doing wrong for having so much memory and so slow saving ?

```
-(void)saveToFileWithData:(NSMutableDictionary*)dic
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
         NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
    }
    NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dic];
    BOOL sucess=[myData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    if(sucess)
        NSLog(@"saved:%lu",(unsigned long)[myData length]);
    else
        NSLog(@"failed:%lu",[myData length]);

     myData=nil;

}
```

The reading is like this :

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*)readFromFile
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"]; //3

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]; //5
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSData *serialized = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];


    //check first if file exist, than if it has content(empty file had 42 bytes-and crashes the archiver)
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] && [serialized length]>1000000)
       dic = (NSMutableDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:serialized];


    serialized=nil;
    return dic;


}
```

Use them with :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dic = [self readFromFile];
   //change dic
[self saveToFileWithData:dic];
```

Comment: How big is the plist? Is it necessary to copy the plist file to the Documents directory for some other reason?

Comment: i dont know if i need to copy it... we are having more than 100 images, we would like to read and write to it. it can be even a 500M. is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: You were "told" that `NSUserDefaults` is slower.  Did you try it?

Comment: yes i did tried it , it took about 2 seconds to save, even less. but i read that saving 500M to defaults is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to copy the plist from the app bundle to the Documents directory just to read it.

A plist is not a good solution, in this case it is huge Put the images individual files and the image file names in the plist. Read the now small plist and then rest the images one by one. Reading each file individually uses a smaller amount of memory.

But, do you really want 500MB of images in memory all at once? After having read the plist of image information just read the images as needed, perhaps with a cache that purges images based on usage.

Comment: thanks, as the previous answer, i dont really get what you say. what so big dill of having 500M ? this is an iPad app, that saves images to later use .  Anyway, i didnt really understand practically what is your answer, how to save the images to files (by the way , just to save their reference i can use user defaults and not plist )

Comment: and what do you mean in memory "all at once" ? i just need a place to store data in the iPad . it can be big amount of data. but i dont understand what is "at once" .

Comment: 1) Why have all the images in memory if they do not need to be? 2) The questions was about high memory usage. A large plist file will cause a large memory usage spike. First the plist data has to be read in, then each image extracted into it's own memory and there may well be additional temp memory used in the process by the system. Also the copy from the app to the Documents directory used memory.

Comment: If you have the images in individual files in the app then they will already be "stored" in the app. "all at once" means all images in memory at the same time.

Comment: ok. so what is the bottom line ? what should i do? what should i read about ?

Comment: or, question is, how you save images, to later load into some tableview ? how camera+ do that? or other apps? what is the right way to go ?

Comment: by the way, the sum of the data is 500MB ,but each album is 70M so i need only to have that 70M ready for me.

Comment: Put the individual images in the app. Come up with a scheme of knowing the images in the app, that could be a plist with the image file names and any other additional information. Read them individually into memory when needed, that may mean all of them in memory at one time.